# localstack AWS S3 connection refused with no errors

Tags: java, amazon-s3, junit, testcontainers, localstack

I'm running localstack 3.0.2 to test a Spring Boot app using aws-java-sdk as an integration test using TestContainers. I need to simulate querying a very large number of S3 objects so I generate a ton of objects (as basic text files) using a structured path that my code needs to navigate and be performant. When I hit around 1 million objects generated my Junit test will throw:

> com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to 127.0.0.1:32822 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused

```
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1219)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1165)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5520)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5467)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:422)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:6601)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1891)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1851)
```

The docker logs do not show any errors from the container.

There is no consistent specific number of objects where it bombs like this. I can run the same test up to about 950,000 objects fairly consistently but I'd like to get to 2-15 million for different versions of the testing I want to perform. I know this may not be suitable for a TestContainer but before resigning myself to finding a new way to test what I'm looking to test, I'd like to understand the cause of this issue and what my remedies might be.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStack stores S3 Objects in memory in they don't go over a certain size threshold (512kb), after which they will be stored on disk in a temporary file. It looks like your container might run out of memory and get killed, which would lead into the `Connection refused` error.

Maybe you could try to raise your container's available memory and see if you can upload more data?

Comment: I suspected that and tried but it dies with no errors the same way.
`@Container`
`static LocalStackContainer localStack = new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:3.0.2"))`
`.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withHostConfig(cmd.getHostConfig().withMemory((long) 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)))`
`.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withHostConfig(cmd.getHostConfig().withMemorySwap((long) 16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)));`

I watched `docker stats` to verify the memory limit wasn't reached at the time it died.